# How to apply texture on irregular shapes in 2d image?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

[image]

I'm trying to apply texture on CALayer from UIColor pattern image. Texture is applying but it's not correctly perspective transformed. Looks like there is an issue with my drawing logic i.e I need to use a texture image and map it on to the irregular shape. I did some research and come to know this thing can be achievable through OpenGL or metal by mapping texture image to irregular shape in 2d image.

Looking for some kind of guidance, How i can correctly perspective transform tile patterns?

```
        let image = UIImage(named: "roofTiles_square")?.flattened
        
        if let realImage = image {
            let color = UIColor(patternImage: realImage)
            controller.quadView.quadLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please add expected output image also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am writing up a detailed solution, but I want make sure I am solving the correct problem. The plan is to create a transformation that properly warps a version of the "roof tile" pattern (or any such pattern) such that when mapped to the quadrilateral in the image on the right is correctly perspectively warped? i.e, the quad ABCE is mapped to the quad A'B'C'E'?

[image]

The first step is to compute a [homography](https://mattmaulion.medium.com/homography-transform-image-processing-eddbcb8e4ff7) that maps the quad ABCD to the quad A'B'C'D'. [OpenCV provides methods for this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html), but lets do that math ourself. We are searching for a 3x3 matrix H that maps the points A,B,C,D to the points A',B',C',D' as follows (we'll actually do it the other way around):

[image]

Using 3D homogenous vectors (x,y,w) allows us to work in 3-D and the division by w provides the necessary perspective foreshortening (to make a long story short).
It turns out that any scale multiple of H works meaning that it only has 8 degrees of freedom (instead of the full 3*3 = 9). What this means is that we want H**A'** to be a scale multiple of **A** thus their cross product is zero:

[image]

If we perform the cross product we can rewrite this last equation as

[image]

The last equation above is actually a linear combination of the first two equations (multiply the first equation by x, multiply the second equation by y, add them and you arrive at the third equation). Since the third equation in linearly dependent we throw it out and only use the first two. After negating the second equation, swapping them, and then converting them to matrix form we get

[image]

Thus one point correspondence **A'** - **A** yields two equations.
If we have n point correspondences we get 2n equations:

[image]

We need n >= 4 to have at least 8 equations to arrive at a proper solution; i.e., we need at least 4 (non-collinear) points.
Thus we have a homogenous system of equations which
we solve using [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition):

[image]

Obviously the trivial solution h = 0 works but it not very useful.
Setting h to the last column of V leads to the least squared
error solution of our system where h has unit length.

Lets compute H for your specific example. Let's assume the source
image to transform is WxH = 500x300, thus A = (0,0), B = (W,0), C = (0,H), and D = (W,H). The destination image is 484x217 and I located
the corners of the roof as A' = (70.7, 41.3), B' = (278.8, 76.3),
C' = (136.4, 121,2), and D' = (345.1, 153,2). I'll use [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to
do the computation. So I'll load my source and destination
points into matrices:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
...
constexpr double W = 500;
constexpr double H = 300;
constexpr size_t N = 4;

Eigen::Matrix<double,2,N> SRC;
SRC <<
    0, W, 0, W,
    0, 0, H, H;
Eigen::Matrix<double,2,N> DST;
DST <<
    70.7, 278.8, 136.4, 345.1,
    41.3,  76.3, 121.2, 153.2;
```

I construct the 8x9 matrix A as described above

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,2*N,9> A;
A.setZero();
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    const double x_ = DST(0,i), y_ = DST(1,i);
    const double x  = SRC(0,i), y  = SRC(1,i);
    A(2*i,0) = A(2*i+1,3) = x_;
    A(2*i,1) = A(2*i+1,4) = y_;
    A(2*i,2) = A(2*i+1,5) = 1;
    A(2*i,6) = -x*x_;
    A(2*i,7) = -x*y_;
    A(2*i,8) = -x;
    A(2*i+1,6) = -y*x_;
    A(2*i+1,7) = -y*y_;
    A(2*i+1,8) = -y;
}
```

I then compute the SVD, extract the solution from the
last column of V, and stored the result in a 3x3 matrix:

```
Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::Matrix<double,2*N,9>> svd(A, Eigen::ComputeFullV);
Eigen::Matrix<double,9,1> h = svd.matrixV().col(8);
Eigen::Matrix3d Homography;
Homography <<
    h(0), h(1), h(2),
    h(3), h(4), h(5),
    h(6), h(7), h(8);
```

yielding the desired 3x3 matrix H:

```
  -0.016329     0.013427      0.599927
   0.004571    -0.0271779     0.799277
   1.78122e-06 -2.83812e-06  -0.00613631
```

We can take a look at a sample warped image using OpenCV.
I load my source texture and my homography H and use the OpenCV
[`warpPerspective` function](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat sourceImage = imread("texture.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    cv::Matx33d H(-0.016329, 0.013427, 0.599927,
                  0.004571, -0.0271779, 0.799277,
                  1.78122e-06, -2.83812e-06, -0.00613631);
    cv::Mat destImage;
    cv::warpPerspective(sourceImage, destImage, H, cv::Size(487,217),
                        cv::INTER_LINEAR | cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
    cv::imwrite("warped.png", destImage);
    return 0;
}
```

The result looks plausible:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, Exactly right. The quad ABCD (LHS) should map to the quad A'B'C'E' (RHS). Then I need to add one more thing which is tile size based on base length in the above case which is AB or CE of the selected portion. I think i can handle tile size logic by simply resizing image of pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much. What if the selected portion is a hexagon or n corner shape? I added a screenshot in question body.

Comment: A homography perspectively maps any planar set of points to any other planar set of points (hexagons and other planar polygons are fine) , but does it all in image space. If you are using OpenGL and have a 3D model, then you would assign texture coordinates to each vertex and the face of each polygon would be filled such that the texture would be properly warped for the perspective transformation. A homography is used more in computer vision when all you have is the image, not the underlying 3D model.

Comment: Thank you so so much professor for such a detailed answer.

Comment: actually, i was asking the edit in code at OpenCV Step. Apologies for not being clear. Actually i tried and able to change the RGB value of black pixel to white but unable to make it transparent.

Comment: Could you pls review.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415631/how-to-compute-homography-for-triangle-and-hexagon

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same way it was done for the main part of the roof with a Parallelogram, that is, if you don't care how its going to look inside the house...
[image]

Well they say a picture is worth a 1000 words. The above picture I modified shows the parallelogram in green that you should texture map onto. Presumably the right part of it will get Z-sorted underneth the main roof. The same thing happens in the attic of some houses were the builder does not have to pay for materials, but instead is paid by the hour. They will just cut into the roof and slot-in a rectilinear prefab...

Comment: Sorry! Could you please elaborate?

Comment: There is way to get the proper perspective distortion by computing a homography. I could write up a solution if you want, but it might be more than you are looking for,

Comment: @wcochran Thank you so much professor. I applied solid color that's looking as you mentioned in the image but I'm creating color from image pattern. In that case the output is as in above attachment. Looks like your answer will work. Please share. Thank so much again

Comment: You could also fake a homography in Photoshop or Gimp by putting your texture on the parallelogram then reverting it back to the original shape then do a screengrab to make your new texture. I would only go through that hassle if it was important to have your attic space clear, like if you're putting an HVAC system model in there...

Comment: @wcochran Still waiting for your answer. Thanks

Comment: @YinOrYan Thanks. In my case attic space is not the subject.