# How to compute Homography for Triangle and Hexagon?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, matrix, eigen3

I'm computing Homography for different shapes i.e (QUAD, HEXAGON, TRIANGLE). This logic is working fine for QUAD but not working for Hexagon or triangle. Looks like there is a problem with my matrix calculation logic. Can you pls review?

Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "EigenWrapper.h"
#import <Eigen/Dense>

@implementation EigenWrapper

constexpr double W = 800;
constexpr double H = 800;

constexpr size_t NQUAD = 4;
constexpr size_t NTRI = 3;
constexpr size_t NHEX = 6;

Eigen::Matrix3d Homography;

//QUAD
Eigen::Matrix<double,2,NQUAD> DSTQUAD;
Eigen::Matrix<double,2*NQUAD,9> AQUAD;
Eigen::Matrix<double,2,NQUAD> SRCQUAD;

//Triangle
Eigen::Matrix<double,2,NTRI> DSTTRI;
Eigen::Matrix<double,2*NTRI,9> ATRI;
Eigen::Matrix<double,2,NTRI> SRCTRI;

//HEXA
Eigen::Matrix<double,2,NHEX> DSTHEX;
Eigen::Matrix<double,2*NHEX,9> AHEX;
Eigen::Matrix<double,2,NHEX> SRCHEX;


- (instancetype)initEigenWrapper:(size_t)sides {
    return  self;
}

+ (double*)eigenGetHomogprahyMatrix :(double)topLeftX : (double)topLeftY :(double)topRightX :(double)topRightY :(double)bottomLeftX  :(double)bottomLeftY  :(double)bottomRightX  :(double)bottomRightY  {
    
    SRCQUAD <<
        0, W, 0, W,
        0, 0, H, H;

    DSTQUAD <<
    topLeftX, topRightX, bottomLeftX, bottomRightX,
    topLeftY,  topRightY,bottomLeftY, bottomRightY;
    

    AQUAD.setZero();
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NQUAD; i++) {
        const double x_ = DSTQUAD(0,i), y_ = DSTQUAD(1,i);
        const double x  = SRCQUAD(0,i), y  = SRCQUAD(1,i);
        AQUAD(2*i,0) = AQUAD(2*i+1,3) = x_;
        AQUAD(2*i,1) = AQUAD(2*i+1,4) = y_;
        AQUAD(2*i,2) = AQUAD(2*i+1,5) = 1;
        AQUAD(2*i,6) = -x*x_;
        AQUAD(2*i,7) = -x*y_;
        AQUAD(2*i,8) = -x;
        AQUAD(2*i+1,6) = -y*x_;
        AQUAD(2*i+1,7) = -y*y_;
        AQUAD(2*i+1,8) = -y;
    }


    
    Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::Matrix<double,2*NQUAD,9>> svd(AQUAD, Eigen::ComputeFullV);
    Eigen::Matrix<double,9,1> h = svd.matrixV().col(8);
    
    Homography <<
        h(0), h(1), h(2),
        h(3), h(4), h(5),
        h(6), h(7), h(8);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n: %f", Homography.array().data()[i]);
    }
    
    return  Homography.array().data();
}
+ (double *)eigenGetHomogprahyTriangle  :(double)middleX :(double)middleY :(double)bottomLeftX  :(double)bottomLeftY  :(double)bottomRightX  :(double)bottomRightY {
    
    SRCTRI <<
         0, W, W/2,
         H, H, 0;

    DSTTRI <<
    bottomLeftX, bottomRightX, middleX,
    bottomLeftY, bottomRightY, middleY;
    

    ATRI.setZero();
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NTRI; i++) {
        const double x_ = DSTTRI(0,i), y_ = DSTTRI(1,i);
        const double x  = SRCTRI(0,i), y  = SRCTRI(1,i);
        ATRI(2*i,0) = ATRI(2*i+1,3) = x_;
        ATRI(2*i,1) = ATRI(2*i+1,4) = y_;
        ATRI(2*i,2) = ATRI(2*i+1,5) = 1;
        ATRI(2*i,6) = -x*x_;
        ATRI(2*i,7) = -x*y_;
        ATRI(2*i,8) = -x;
        ATRI(2*i+1,6) = -y*x_;
        ATRI(2*i+1,7) = -y*y_;
        ATRI(2*i+1,8) = -y;
    }


    
    Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::Matrix<double,2*NTRI,9>> svd(ATRI, Eigen::ComputeFullV);
    Eigen::Matrix<double,9,1> h = svd.matrixV().col(8);
    
    Homography <<
        h(0), h(1), h(2),
        h(3), h(4), h(5),
        h(6), h(7), h(8);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n: %f", Homography.array().data()[i]);
    }
    
    return  Homography.array().data();
}
+ (double *)eigenGetHomogprahyMatrixHexa:(double)topLeftX :(double)topLeftY :(double)topRightX :(double)topRightY :(double)middleLeftX :(double)middleLeftY :(double)middleRightX :(double)middleRightY :(double)bottomLeftX :(double)bottomLeftY :(double)bottomRightX :(double)bottomRightY {
    SRCHEX <<
        0, W, W/2, 0, W, W,
        0, 0, H/2, H, H, H/2;

    DSTHEX <<
    topLeftX, topRightX, middleLeftX,bottomLeftX, bottomRightX, middleRightX,
    topLeftY,  topRightY, middleLeftY, bottomLeftY, bottomRightY, middleRightY;
    

    AHEX.setZero();
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NHEX; i++) {
        const double x_ = DSTHEX(0,i), y_ = DSTHEX(1,i);
        const double x  = SRCHEX(0,i), y  = SRCHEX(1,i);
        AHEX(2*i,0) = AHEX(2*i+1,3) = x_;
        AHEX(2*i,1) = AHEX(2*i+1,4) = y_;
        AHEX(2*i,2) = AHEX(2*i+1,5) = 1;
        AHEX(2*i,6) = -x*x_;
        AHEX(2*i,7) = -x*y_;
        AHEX(2*i,8) = -x;
        AHEX(2*i+1,6) = -y*x_;
        AHEX(2*i+1,7) = -y*y_;
        AHEX(2*i+1,8) = -y;
    }


    
    Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::Matrix<double,2*NHEX,9>> svd(AHEX, Eigen::ComputeFullV);
    Eigen::Matrix<double,9,1> h = svd.matrixV().col(8);
    
    Homography <<
        h(0), h(1), h(2),
        h(3), h(4), h(5),
        h(6), h(7), h(8);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n: %f", Homography.array().data()[i]);
    }
    
    return  Homography.array().data();
}

@end
```

After computing homogrphy, I'm just wrapping the texture image with OpenCV. I'm also want to change the background of the out image from black to transparent.

```
    cv::Mat sourceImage = imread("texture.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf(":- %.7f", homographyMatrix[i]);
    }
    
    cv::Matx33d H(homographyMatrix[0], homographyMatrix[3], homographyMatrix[6],
                  homographyMatrix[1], homographyMatrix[4], homographyMatrix[7],
                  homographyMatrix[2], homographyMatrix[5], homographyMatrix[8]);
    cv::Mat destImage;


    cv::warpPerspective(sourceImage, destImage, H, cv::Size(width,height),
                        cv::INTER_LINEAR | cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP);

    

    UIImage * deImage = MatToUIImage(destImage);
```

Here is the outPut for Hexagon

[image]

Here is the outPut for Triangle

[image]

Thanks

Comment: A quick comment for the moment: a triangle does not have enough points to compute a homography which has 8 degrees of freedom -- you get 2 constraints per point (2*3 = 6 < 8 so not enough).

Comment: @wcochran
So you mean we can't compute it for triangle? also i'm not able to compute right homography for hexagon. Looks like this will only work with 4 points to 4 points mapping as we did for QUAD. My plan for hexagon is to compute the homography first for (TopLeft, TopRight, MiddleLeft, MiddleRight) and then for ( MiddleLeft, MiddleRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight) and then mege the both output images. Whats your take on this?

Comment: 3 is not enough. 4 or more (3d co-planar) points will work ... actually the more the merrier...